# How to set environment variable by bat in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'd like to set the env variable based on the execute result of bat. When `compile.bat` return `1`, how to set `env.BuildResult` as `FAILURE`?

```
node("test")
{
    env.BuildResult='SUCCESS'
    stage('Compile')
    {
        bat'''
            call compile.bat    
            if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 SET BuildResult='FAILURE'
        '''
    }
    stage('Post')
    {
        bat'''
            echo %BuildResult%
        ''''
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it to the level of pipeline

```
def res = bat script:'call compile.bat', returnStatus:true
if( res!= 0 ) env.BuildResult = 'failure'
```